# Can't initialize static member in Java - Android

Tags: java, android

I've helper `class` named `Prefs` in which I've static `class member` of `interface` `SyncFinishedListener`. Here's they are:

```
public interface SyncFinishedListener {
    void onSyncFinished();
}
```

here's my `Prefs` helper class

```
public class Prefs {
    public static final String TAG = Prefs.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String PrefsName = Prefs.class.getSimpleName();

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    public Prefs(Context context) {
        super();
        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static SyncFinishedListener listener;

    public Prefs(Context context, SyncFinishedListener listener) {
        this(context);
        Prefs.listener = listener;
        SyncUtils.get(context).requestSync(HrEmployee.AUTHORITY);
    }

    private boolean isSyncFinished() {
        boolean isSyncFinished = (isHrEmployeeSyncFinished()
                && isHrAttendanceSyncFinished()
                && isAttReportSyncFinished()
                && isSchoolSchoolSyncFinished()
        );
        Log.e(TAG, "isSyncFinished is :" + isSyncFinished);
        if (isSyncFinished) {
            try {
                setHrEmployeeSyncFinished(false);
                setHrAttendanceSyncFinished(false);
                setAttReportSyncFinished(false);
                setSchoolSchoolSyncFinished(false);
                // Here's NullPointerException
                Prefs.listener.onSyncFinished();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return isSyncFinished;
    }

    private static final String HrEmployeeSyncFinished = "hrEmployeeSyncFinished";
    private static final String HrAttendanceSyncFinished = "hrAttendanceSyncFinished";
    private static final String AttReportSyncFinished = "attReportSyncFinished";
    private static final String SchoolSchoolSyncFinished = "schoolSchoolSyncFinished";

    private boolean isHrEmployeeSyncFinished() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(HrEmployeeSyncFinished, false);
    }

    public Prefs setHrEmployeeSyncFinished(boolean hrEmployeeSyncFinished) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(HrEmployeeSyncFinished, hrEmployeeSyncFinished).apply();
        if (hrEmployeeSyncFinished) {
            isSyncFinished();
        }
        return this;
    }

    private boolean isHrAttendanceSyncFinished() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(HrAttendanceSyncFinished, false);
    }

    public Prefs setHrAttendanceSyncFinished(boolean hrAttendanceSyncFinished) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(HrAttendanceSyncFinished, hrAttendanceSyncFinished).apply();
        if (hrAttendanceSyncFinished) {
            isSyncFinished();
        }
        return this;
    }

    private boolean isAttReportSyncFinished() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(AttReportSyncFinished, false);
    }

    public Prefs setAttReportSyncFinished(boolean attReportSyncFinished) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(AttReportSyncFinished, attReportSyncFinished).apply();
        if (attReportSyncFinished) {
            isSyncFinished();
        }
        return this;
    }

    private boolean isSchoolSchoolSyncFinished() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(SchoolSchoolSyncFinished, false);
    }

    public Prefs setSchoolSchoolSyncFinished(boolean schoolSchoolSyncFinished) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(SchoolSchoolSyncFinished, schoolSchoolSyncFinished).apply();
        if (schoolSchoolSyncFinished) {
            isSyncFinished();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

and here's how I'm calling this from `Fragment`

```
public class Employees extends BaseFragment {

    private static final String TAG = Employees.class.getSimpleName();
    private Prefs mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mPrefs = new Prefs(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_employee, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_sync) {
            return onSync();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private boolean onSync() {
        try {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.AppDialogTheme);
            dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            dialog.setMessage("Syncing Data");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            new Prefs(getContext(), new SyncFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSyncFinished() {
                    // Not getting called
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My code should run fine. but, I can't figure out why I'm getting `NullPointerException`.
Here's some `Log` for debugging.

```
E/HrEmployee: onSyncStarted
E/HrAttendance: onSyncStarted
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncStarted
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrEmployee: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/AttReport: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrAttendance: onSyncStarted
E/HrAttendance: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncStarted
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/AttReport: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrAttendance: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/AttReport: onSyncStarted
E/AttReport: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrAttendance: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrAttendance: onSyncStarted
E/HrAttendance: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncStarted
E/SchoolSchool: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/HrAttendance: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :false
E/AttReport: onSyncFinished
E/Prefs: isSyncFinished is :true
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.SyncFinishedListener.onSyncFinished()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.Prefs.isSyncFinished(Prefs.java:145)
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.Prefs.setAttReportSyncFinished(Prefs.java:115)
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.addons.employees.models.AttReport.onSyncFinished(AttReport.java:58)
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.core.service.OSyncAdapter.syncData(OSyncAdapter.java:291)
W/System.err:     at com.odoo.core.service.OSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(OSyncAdapter.java:204)
W/System.err:     at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:272)
```

Comment: I think the code should run well too. so maybe somewhere else you not noticed set `listener` to null. add a `logcat` before setting `listener` and try again.

Comment: Within the constructor public `Prefs(Context context)` you don't initialize the listeners list. That might cause a problem in `isSyncFinished` where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to track the bug back to its root: You are getting an NPE because your `Prefs.listener` var is null when you call `onSyncFinished()` on it (in `isSyncFinished()`). This variable is assigned in a constructor that takes for second parameter the listener. But there is also a constructor which only takes a context as parameter and if this one is used the `Prefs.listener` remains null. In your fragment you are constructing a Prefs-Object with this constructor in `onCreate()`. This is the only reason I can see for `Prefs.listener` to be null. As your `Prefs.listener` is static you have to make sure the constructor with the listener-assignment is called before `isSyncFinished()` of the other Prefs-object is called.

Hope I could help.

PS: But to assign a static variable in a constructer and hope that this var is initialized for a object that didnt call this constructor is not a good way to realize what you want. Is it necessary for listener to be static?

Answer (score 0):

First there is no reason why you should be calling `super()` in the first constructor, as you are not extending any class.

Second there is no reason why `listener` should be static, in this code at least. If you are calling `Prefs.listener` from outside this code, you should reconsider your whole architecture by removing the static calls. This is a bad habit that can almost always be avoided. If the class has just static variables that are used all over your application, you should think about using the singleton design pattern. It's easy and safe to use once you get used to it.